# Animation not completing transition on SVG hover animation, when hover out occurs fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have made a very simple hover animation for a thumbnail by using a SVG icon. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hkraofzv/1/). The JS code I used is like so:

```
var elemRemoveAnim = null;

$('.vedio-thumb').hover(
    function(){
            $(this).find('.youtube-icon > .youtube-red')[0].classList.add('y-animated' , 'fadeInUp');
            $(this).find('.youtube-icon > .youtube-white')[0].classList.add('y-animated' , 'fadeInUp');
    }, 
    function(){
            removeVedioAnim($(this));
});


function removeVedioAnim(elem) {
    elemRemoveAnim = elem;
    setTimeout(function(){
        elemRemoveAnim.find('.youtube-icon > .youtube-red')[0].classList.remove('y-animated' , 'fadeInUp');
        elemRemoveAnim.find('.youtube-icon > .youtube-white')[0].classList.remove('y-animated' , 'fadeInUp');
    }, 1000);
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to remove the animation class, after a delay of `1000ms`, that's because iif you hover over and immediately hover out (you'll have to do it really fast), you'll notice that the animation gets stuck, i.e. the white arrow will still only be in half transition. Technically this is happening because the animation class has been removed too soon.

If I add the code in the hover out function, this aggravates the situation even more. Is there a more versatile solution to this problem?

One more problem with the with this solution is that once you hover and then if you hover out and you do it 2-3 times really fast, for the 2-3 time you've hovered the animation will take play only once, simply the setTimeout function will wait 1 second to remove the classes. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**[SEE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hkraofzv/6/)**

1. Use "animationend" event to capture the end of fadingInUp motion on the arrow, that runs longer (the white one).

   ```
    $utube_white.one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd",function() {                  
     $utube_red.get(0).classList.remove('y-animated' , 'fadeInUp');
     $utube_white.get(0).classList.remove('y-animated' , 'fadeInUp');
     isLocked = false;
   });
   ```
2. In your example there's no need for a mouseleave function in HOVER event, because you don't do anything particular on it - just remove animation classes without any other motion. This could be done in "Animationend" event in the first "HandlerIn" function. 
   Instead of a mouseleave function put the empty $.noop to prevent jQuery think that your hover function contains only one argument. 
   .hover(handlerIn, $.noop) and not .hover( handlerInOut ). You can change it, it's up to you, but in the last case the function will fire on both MouseOn and MouseOut.
3. Use a flag "isLocked" as well to prevent firing HandlerIn on quick hovers.